# How to backup data from a USB drive attached to a BT HomeHub

Tags: windows, backup, usb-drive

I am running Windows 10 on 2 PCs.

They are both connected to a BT Home Hub which has a USB drive plugged in and the shared data that they use is on that drive.

I want to run a daily backup of that data from one or both PCs to backup the data onto a USB drive attached to the PC(s).

Is there an easy / reliable way to do this ?

I realise there are plenty of back up programs around, both free and purchasable, but the first 2 I have tried (Windows own, though for some reason it specifies itself as Windows 7, and Paragon HD manager free) don't pick up the USB drive attached to the Hub, though I can see it if I go to C / Users / Desktop, where I have a Networked link. I don't want to trial and error every App on the market if I don't need to !!!

I hope this is clear, I just want to back up that USB data in case of a problem, it doesn't have to be anything clever, incremental or even compressed, it's about 5GB of data right now and I have a 1Tb USB drive I can backup onto, so my user can manually delete old data every 6 months if necessary ...

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, this can be closed now, EaseUS Free allows me to do this ... Trial & Error it was !!